# Quais as diferenças entre ADOdb e PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Quais as diferenças entre o ADOdb e PDO? Qual dos dois possui melhor desempenho?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O PDO é padrão no PHP a partir da versão 5.1. (Ele também está disponível com uma extensão PECL em PHP 5.0) A maioria dos provedores de hospedagem terá habilitado. AdoDB não é uma extensão padrão.

Além disso, acredito que os drivers PDO são "nativos do PHP": eles são construídos em cima das mesmas bibliotecas que o próprio PHP foi construído e usam as mesmas rotinas subjacentes para coisas como o gerenciamento de memória. Assim, potencialmente, o PDO é mais leve que o AdoDB.

De acordo com este benchmark, o AdoDB é consideravelmente mais lento que o PDO: (link fixo) http://tonylandis.com/performance/php-adodb-pdo-mysql-database-apc-benchmark/

Claro, você deve considerar se isso é importante o suficiente para o seu caso de uso para preferir PDO ou não.

Traduzido de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943051/what-are-the-differences-between-adodb-and-pdo-in-php